# How to show different views in same window in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it possible to do navigation within the same window in a mac application ?(Like it is possible in ios apps).I want to show each view in the same window instead of opening different windows on a button click.
e.g When a user clicks a button then the next page should be loaded in the same window.(The next page will have nothing in common with the current page.)

Comment: Well you can take different view in xib and then on the basis of your condition load view on window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **Tab View** for easy switching between views on a same window.

UPDATE:

You may also customize your tab view , make it tabless (In the attributes inspector set style to tabless) and use your buttons to switch between views.
You may take help from the following link : http://devcry.heiho.net/2012/01/nstabview-tutorial.html

OR

You may add or remove subviews from your window on button clicks, using

```
[[yourWindow contentView] addSubview: yourSubview]; // Add subview to window

[yourSubview removeFromSuperview];   //Remove subview
```

UPDATE:

Steps to swap between views using a tabless tab view.

1. Drag a NSTabView to your xib.
2. Set the no. of tabs in attribute inspector to no. of views you want.
3. Design each view of the tab as per your requirement.
4. Now in the attribute inspector of tabview, set style to tabless.
5. Now drag the buttons you want to use for swapping between views. Suppose Button0 and Button1 are for 1st and 2nd view of your tab view.
6. Create a IBOutlet for your NSTabView in your .h file. Bind it to the referencing outlet of you tabview.
    `IBOutLet NSTabView* tabview;`
7. Set a IBAction for both your buttons in your .h class file.
8. In the button action method for button1, use

   `- (IBAction)button1clicked:(id)sender`

   `{
      [tab selectTabViewItemAtIndex:0];
    }`
9. Similarly in button2 action method use:

   [tab selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];

In this way you can have any no. of views and you may select any view on button click using
    [tab selectTabViewItemAtIndex:(index of the view you want to load)];

Comment: I cant show tabs.When a user clicks a button then the next page should be loaded in the same window.

Comment: This is called view swapping. NSTabView also does not need to actually display any tabs. Please RTFM at least a little bit.

Comment: I think this it what @Worker is asking for. Swapping views on a button click. Isn't it?

Comment: @Neha yes Swapping entire views on a single click.

Comment: @Neha But I dont want any tabs on my window.Just buttons.

Comment: Yes i have updated my answer for the same, you only have to set actions on your button and add or remove views from window accordingly on button click

Comment: @Neha I have upvoted your answer(and all your comments) for your idea.But I'll try to get it to work before selecting as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to google for view swapping. 
There are tons of examples out there. Some from Apple and lots elsewhere. 
Much of it is very similar to iOS. 
You need to read the docs a bit too. 
Understand `NSView` and how to load views from nibs, how to create view objects in code, how to add a subview and how to remove a view.

There are many approaches to having different views for different reasons. The right approach is a combination of style, experience and what your app actually needs to do.

Cocoa includes `NSBox`, `NSTabView`, and lots of others. Those two can be configured to not display any visual indication that they are containers. 
You will also need to understand at least a little about `NSWindow` to understand its content view (the root container of other views generally)